# gem command raises UnsatisfiableDependencyError in rails project folder, but works with sudo, or when called from another folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, gemfile

I have a rails project in the myapp folder.

```
# in my_app folder
$ gem -v
...
ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:406:in `resolve_for_zero': Unable to resolve dependency: 'rails (= 4.1.5, = 4.1.5)' requires 'bundler (< 2.0, >= 1.3.0)' (Gem::UnsatisfiableDependencyError)
...
$ sudo gem -v
Password:
2.4.2

# revoke sudo privileges
$ sudo -k 
$ cd
# in home directory now 
$ gem -v
2.4.2
```

The Gemfile of my rails project is [here](https://gist.github.com/rcanand/bf647de46f91dfddaddf) and the Gemfile.lock is [here](https://gist.github.com/rcanand/042fad45ba3f5d2a09c2). I realize this has something to do with the Gemfile, but have no idea how to fix it.

There is a fix for a similar, but worse issue [#886](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/886) in rubygems 2.4.2 with [this commit](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/commit/ab28a37) . I have upgraded to rubygems 2.4.2 (I had to use `sudo gem update --system` as `gem update --system` gave the same error at the time), but the current issue still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had previously fixed a closely related rubygems problem by setting `export RUBYGEMS_GEMDEPS=-` in my `.bash_profile`, which was causing this error.  that issue has since been fixed with an update, and this bash setting was causing the current problem described above. Removing this line from `.bash_profile` fixed the problem.